# How to set generator default style to scss, in a Nativescript / Angular 8 project?

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular-cli, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

When I use the cli generator, by default it creates a css file, instead of scss.

With the command:

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss
```

It appends the new configuration to the `angular.json` file, but generated components are still css.

I'm using the following command to generate new components:

```
ng generate component <name>
OR 
ng g c <name>
```

There's a way to change the default style, or we need to send a feature request?

**Note**:
I've tried to generate a new project, with `--style=scss`, apparently it just generates the first components with scss ext., but I don't see the setting stored anywhere.
In fact, if I generate another component, it uses css.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about the command you are using to create the styles file.

Comment: You're righ!  I've updated the question with the command that I'm using. tx

Comment: I am experiencing the same frustrations as the OP (and using the same commands).